# Converter horas em segundos Access

Tags: microsoft-access

Preciso converter horas em segundos dentro de uma VIEW dentro do Access.

Tenho uma coluna dentro de uma tabela, onde tenho dados em horas(acima de 24h), porém preciso converter todos os dados em uma VIEW para somente segundos como no exemplo abaixo:

Valor que tenho: 24:00:00
Valor que preciso: 86400

Teria alguma fórmula no Access que eu possa colocar em uma VIEW para transformar estes dados?
Tentei com a fórmula Format, porém somente me traz segundos com máximo de 2 casas.

Answer (score 1):

[De acordo com esse site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/convert-hhmmss-to-seconds/06ad9442-ae06-4639-ac74-3e80f4265d58), o Access armazena tempo como fração de um dia, então se tu multiplicares por `86400`, que é o número de segundos em um dia, tu terás o valor desejado caso teu campo possua apenas "horas" (ou melhor, tempo decorrido).

Todavia, se teu campo possui data e hora, é necessário primeiro separar esses valores para fazer essa operação.

Comment: Perfeito, tentei isso também antes, pois é o que mais fazia sentido e que seria simples, porém quando coloco essa fórmula, ele me devolve como erro. Segue fórmula que estou usando  - [Consolidado_Analitico_Exportacao].[Tempo de Atendimento]*86400

Comment: Qual mensagem de erro?

Comment: Não retorna um erro no construtor, ele devolve como #erro na própria tabela